# python regex to find string from multi line curley braces

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a string like this. How to create a dictionary with First-tags as key and everything after : as value?

```
test_string = """###Some Comment 
First-tags : 
{
  "tag1": {
    "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
    "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "tag2": {
    "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
    "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
  }
  so on .....
} 
"""
```

example:
key will be First-tags
and value will be

```
{
  "tag1": {
    "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
    "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "tag2": {
    "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
    "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
  }
  so on .....
}
```

[Edit: The string data is in a file. Problem is to read from file and create a dictionary where key will be the comment and value will be the Json data]

for example, file will have :

```
###Some Comment 
    First-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
      so on .....
    } 


###2nd Comment 
    Second-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
      so on .....
    } 

###Some other Comment 
    someother-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
      so on .....
    }
```

Comment: are you asking how to parse a `json` string which includes comments into a dictionary? This seems a bit more complicated than that; will the string always contain `First-tags`?

Comment: are you asking how to parse a json string which includes comments into a dictionary?
Yes but the file structure will be like this:

comments
JSON data

Another comment
JSON data

So on...

First-tags is just an example. it can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will match the last set of word characters (including `-`) before a `:` into group 1, and then everything else up to the next comment (`###`) or end of string into group 2:

```
([\w-]+)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*###|$)
```

Then you can make a dictionary by iterating over the two groups for each match in the string:

```
import re

test_string = """
###Some Comment 
    First-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
      so on .....
    } 


###2nd Comment 
    Second-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
      so on .....
    } 

###Some other Comment 
    someother-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
      so on .....
    }
"""
res = {}
for match in re.finditer(r'([\w-]+)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*###|$)', test_string, re.S):
    res[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{
 'First-tags': '{\n      "tag1": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      },\n      "tag2": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      }\n      so on .....\n    }',
 'Second-tags': '{\n      "tag1": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      },\n      "tag2": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      }\n      so on .....\n    }',
 'someother-tags': '{\n      "tag1": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      },\n      "tag2": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      }\n      so on .....\n    }'
}
```

**Update**

If you also wish to fetch the comments, you can use this code:

```
res = {}
for match in re.finditer(r'###([^\n]+)\s*([\w-]+)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*###|$)', test_string, re.S):
    res[match.group(1)] = { match.group(2) : match.group(3) }

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{
 'Some Comment ': {
   'First-tags': '{\n      "tag1": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      },\n      "tag2": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      }\n      so on .....\n    }'
 },
'2nd Comment ': {
   'Second-tags': '{\n      "tag1": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      },\n      "tag2": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      }\n      so on .....\n    }'
 },
 'Some other Comment ': {
  'someother-tags': '{\n      "tag1": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      },\n      "tag2": {\n        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",\n        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"\n      }\n      so on .....\n    }'
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would it work If I have a file with multiple such occurrence. I made an edit to the problem statement.

Comment: @HarshKumar please see my edit. It uses `re.finditer` to find all the matches in the string.

Comment: Is it possible to get the comment as well? i.e print ###Some Comment as well

Comment: @HarshKumar you keep moving the goal posts... how do you want the comment returned?

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have been more clear.
Something like this:

res[comment][match.group(1)] = match.group(2)

Comment: But how do you want the comment stored in the output?

Comment: may be a 2 dimensional dict something like  res[comment][match.group(1)] = match.group(2)

Comment: @HarshKumar see my edit - that will give you that result

Answer (score 0):

So here I am trying to convert the string to JSON

But for that to work my str should just be JSON and nothing else

so I am finding the first `{` and taking the string from there

```
import json

my_str = '''
First-tags : 
{
  "tag1": {
    "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
    "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "tag2": {
    "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
    "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
  }
  }
  '''
# find the first {
i = my_str.index('{')
my_str = my_str[i:] # trim the string so that only dict is left
my_dict = dict(json.loads(my_str)) # create JSON and then convert that to dict
print(my_dict) # n'joy
```

If you want you can also look for end of JSON and trim the str (find `}`)

### solution update based on update in your question

```
import json

my_str = '''
###Some Comment 
    First-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
    } 


###2nd Comment 
    Second-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
    } 

###Some other Comment 
    someother-tags : 
    {
      "tag1": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      },
      "tag2": {
        "tagKey1": "tagValue1",
        "tagKey2": "tagValue2"
      }
    } 
'''
data = []
bal = 0
start = end = 0
for i,v in enumerate(my_str):
    if v == '{': 
        if bal == 0:
            start = i
        bal+=1
    elif v=='}': 
        bal-=1
        end = i
    if start!=end and bal ==0: # just looking for data in {....}
        new_str = my_str[start:end+1]
        print(new_str)
        my_dict = dict(json.loads(new_str))
        data .append(my_dict)
        start = end = i+1
print(data) # n'joy
```

```
[{'tag1': {'tagKey1': 'tagValue1', 'tagKey2': 'tagValue2'}, 'tag2': {'tagKey1': 'tagValue1', 'tagKey2': 'tagValue2'}}, {'tag1': {'tagKey1': 'tagValue1', 'tagKey2': 'tagValue2'}, 'tag2': {'tagKey1': 'tagValue1', 'tagKey2': 'tagValue2'}}, {'tag1': {'tagKey1': 'tagValue1', 'tagKey2': 'tagValue2'}, 'tag2': {'tagKey1': 'tagValue1', 'tagKey2': 'tagValue2'}}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution will work for my earlier problem but  I made an edit to the problem statement. appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, Thank you for your help. I have accepted the other solution using regex. Your approach is also good but for my use case I found regex will help better. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, I am glad your query is solved!